# Multiple identical I2C sensors with the vl53L0x API (ST Microelectronics)

Tags: c, gcc, sensors, stm32, i2c

In a professional context, I have to use the vl53L0x. This sensor was released recently, along with it's API, meaning that there's no help on the internet yet :

http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/proximity-sensors-software/stsw-img005.html

This API contains some source and headers file, that I compiled with the gcc. It works fine, despite clearly lacking comments. I flash the memory of a stm32 (NUCLEO-F401RE), which controls a vl53L0x sensor via an I2C bus. I now want to add more vl53L0x sensors on the same I2C bus, and refer to this document (if you want to read it, go directly to the bottom half of the page 5, the wiring is already done) :

http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/0e/0a/96/1b/82/19/4f/c2/DM00280486/files/DM00280486.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00280486.pdf

The principle, that I already applied on other sensors, is that they all start with the same address. You then have to activate one, change it's address, then activate the next one, change it's address, etc.

Unfortunately, ST Microelectronics didn't publish the list of the I2C registers, so I have to use their API to control multiple sensors. The document linked above explains how to do so. Among other things, it specifies :

```
In vl53L0x_platform.h API file
• Set VL53L0x_SINGLE_DEVICE_DRIVER macro to 0 so that API implementation will
be automatically adapted to a multi-device context.
```

I looked everywhere in the API folder, I was not able to find any reference to a VL53L0x_SINGLE_DEVICE_DRIVER macro. Setting it to 0 won't change anything, as this string is not present anywhere in the API files. Did anyone run into a similar problem ?

Comment: Does it work if you don't set the VL53L0x_SINGLE_DEVICE_DRIVER macro? It's entirely possible that the API has been changed to always accept multiple devices but the documentation has not been updated.

Comment: It works fine if I don't or if I do. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Does that mean your question is answered?

Comment: I'll probably need someone who already did what I'm trying to do. The provided manual tells me to do something that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same thing. It seems that you're further ahead than I am. However, putting this in my while(1) loop seems to make both the sensors work.

```
ResetAndDetectSensor(0);
TimeStamp_Reset();
```

The guide says that in order to use all the sensors simultaneously, you need to pull the XSHUT pin high for all the sensors, reset the timestamp and then pick up the sensor which actually detects something.